# How to create custom middleware in reactjs to update reducer?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, middleware, redux-reducers

I want to update reducer when api sends response with updated token.
I have tried dispatching action from middleware but reducer is resetting to its initial state.

Comment: Welcome to community plz read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting the question

Answer (score 0):

when you reloading one of the component of your app its like you have a new app so whole app will mount and render. every component will mount so the state in reducer will reset too
you have to save that token you get from api in local Storage then in the root component of you app in the componentDidMount() you should dispatch an action and you have get that token you got in local Storage and save it in reducer state this way you always have that token in the reducer state

Comment: Thanks @Amir I have done same. The problem is i want to update reducer as soon as I hit any api  and in axios interceptor response I get updated token . Is there any way to do same?

Comment: axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  let token = response?.data?.token;
  if (!!token) {
   let oldToken = localStorage.getItem('Authorization');
    //Update only if token changes
    if (!!token && !!oldToken && oldToken.localeCompare(token) !== 0) {
      localStorage.setItem('Authorization', token);
      let decodedToken= decodeToken(token); //Written a function to decode token
      const store = configureStore();
      store.dispatch(setData(decodedToken));
    }
  } return response;
});